# Transition states for processes

Tags: state, transition

I am just learning the process state transition diagrams and im a bit puzzled by a question.

[This is what the diagram looks like](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/83/Process_states.svg/640px-Process_states.svg.png)

So the question i have been given is,

For the following transitions, state if the transition is possible, and if it is, list an event that can cause it.

```
i)New --> Running
ii)New --> Blocked
iii)Running --> Terminated
iv)Running --> Blocked
v)Ready --> Blocked
```

From my understanding, the only transitions that are possible are the ones that are directly or in some way connected to the arrows as illustrated by the arrows in the in diagram. So, for (iii) I have written:

> Yes, Terminated by OS if the process indicates that it has been completed or aborted.

So for something like i), ii), and v), transitions arent possible?

Would appreciate if someone could explain this topic.

Comment: This question feels generally homeworky, and very much nothing to do with C.  Any reason you picked that language?  To answer the question, however, one state can transition to another if there is an arrow directly connecting them.  If there's not, there are either intermediate states that it has to go through, or it is not possible.

Comment: i chose c because thats the language that we are learning this through. Thanks for your answer, i'll dig deeper to find the answers for those 3.

Comment: Ah, please remove the tag, it is NOT relevant.